# url issues with django

Tags: python, django, url

I can't get my urls to work for django no matter what I try

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url
from catalog import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^fruit/?$', views.fruit_catalogue, name='fruit_catalogue'),
    re_path(r'^fruit/?$', views.fruit_details),
    re_path(r'^fruit/(?P<fruit_id>[1-7]{1})/?$', views.fruit_details),
]
```

Comment: why do you have ? at the end of your regex, also which path are you trying to get

Comment: The patterns for `fruit_catalogue` and `fruit_details` are the same. How do you expect the view `fruit_details` to be used? Django always uses the first matching url pattern for a request so `fruit_details` will never be used, instead `fruit_catalogue` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 url.py files that you should check for the correct functioning of the URLs.

First the one, that is in your project, that should look something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("NAMEOFAPP.urls")),
]
```

and the other is inside your app. and a simple version of it should look something like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("home", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register") 
]
```

Try to use this same setup and you should be perfectly fine.